# Not displaying some text in a xml node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml document which has a node that contains a proper name then a dash (-) followed by a description. I want to only display the proper name.

```
<productroot>
   <name>Proper name - lots of text not relevant to my display.</name>
</productroot>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "name/text()[contains(., ' -')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' -')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the XML document below**:

```
<productroot>
    <name>Proper name1 - Irrelevant 1</name>
    <name>Proper name2 - Irrelevant 2</name>
    <name>Proper name3 - Irrelevant 3</name>
    <name>Proper name4 - Irrelevant 4</name>
    <name>Proper name5 - Irrelevant 5</name>
</productroot>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<productroot>
   <name>Proper name1</name>
   <name>Proper name2</name>
   <name>Proper name3</name>
   <name>Proper name4</name>
   <name>Proper name5</name>
</productroot>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Overriding the [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. **Use of the standard XPath functions [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) and [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring-before)**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `name` element is the current node:

```
normalize-space(substring-before(., '-'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 2.0 option using `tokenize()`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize(.,'-')[1])"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```